# I'm trying to set an option in a Select on a Razor page as disabled dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to set one of the options that is in an IEnumerable as diasabled within the Razor page. The reason for wanting it to be in the list but disabled is that the database will hold the StatusId but I need the user to choose one of the other options but for the database Status to be selected when the page loads.

This is the Razor syntax I'm using and it's populating the list as expected.

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Status" class="control-label"></label>
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Status" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Statuses, "StatusId", "Description"))">
        <option disabled>Select Status</option>
    </select>
<span asp-validation-for="@Model.Status"></span>
```

What I am looking to do is have an item (it's got an StatusId of 0) set as disabled. How can this be achieved in code?

I would like the resulting HTML to look something like this

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label" for="Description">Description</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Status field is required." id="Status" name="Status">
        <option disabled>Select Status</option>
        <option value="1">Status 1</option>
        <option value="5">Status 2</option>
        <option value="99">Status 3</option>
        <option disabled selected="selected" value="0">Not Selectable Status</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Is this achievable?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with foreach loop to build the options. I exactly don't know the property names so I took Disabled, Value, Text (you can modify as per your model)

PS: correct if there are any syntax errors

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label" for="Description">Description</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Status field is required." id="Status" name="Status">
        <option disabled>Select Status</option>
        @foreach(var s in Model.Statuses)
        {
           if (s.Disabled)
           {
             <option disabled  value="@s.Value">@s.Text</option>
           }
           else
           {
              <option value="@s.Value">@s.Text</option>
           }
        }
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```